# Build artifact from generated pom and sources

Tags: java, maven

I have a java maven project with only a pom.xml file :

```
pom.xml
```

This pom use a code generator ([swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) in my case) to generate a whole project tree in target/generated-sources, my new project tree is:

```
pom.xml
target
  generated-sources
    pom.xml
      src
        ...
```

My question is : How to build artifact from my generated project in target/generated-sources ?

Answer (score 1):

Update your `pom.xml` with:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>target/generated-sources/src</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: In this case, it will not use my generated pom.xml in target/generated-sources

Comment: So, what pom will you use for building your project? the one in folder target/generated-sources or the one out?

Comment: both, the first one to generate sources, the second one to generate artifact. Maybe trying to use both in one call is the bad way, I don't know.

Comment: I guess, the first you run build in the parent folder which contains the first pom for generating source. The second you cd /target/generated-sources and run build for building the artifact, isnt it? Now you want to combine it in the outter pom for run one time, isnt it?

Comment: I think the easiest way is execute shell in the outter pom. I still find a solution for you but why you dont follow maven architecture. :D

Comment: I'm trying to use code generated with a given code-generator. Another way is to ignore generated pom.xml and update root pom with needed dependencies in order to succeeded build.